# Why is there a setter property in C# when deserializing JSON?

Tags: c#, json

When deserializing from JSON to C# objects, why is there a setter property when you technically you are only "getting" the property from a deserialized JSON object? Wouldn't it be appropriate to just have:

```
public class Json
{
    public string MyKey { get; }
}
```

Rather than:

```
public class Json
{
    public string MyKey { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not 100% clear as to why I need the "set" property there for my use-case?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: if there's only get key, it'll always return null because it doesn't setted as value.

Comment: Oh I see, that's where my logic was missing. When I run this 
`public static filejson getjson()
        {
            var file = File.ReadAllText("file.json");
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<filejson>(file);
}`
It uses the "set" to actually set the value of the property.

Comment: What happened when you tried to deserialize into your read-only Json class? Please [edit] post to show your attempt and results, otherwise post looks like you have not even tried that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are deserializing, you are taking the values from the json string and setting them in the c# object so you need the setters to populate the object.

If you were serializing the c# object to a json string, then you would only need the getter because you are getting the values from the c# object.

Answer (score 0):

The JSon Deserializer has to create an instance of your objects and restore their state (the values of their properties) from the serialized Json Stream.
In order to do so, It needs to be able to inject those value in the instances, either by setting their properties (for which it needs a public setter) or by passing them as a parameter to an appropriate constructor (one which has a parameter of the same name and type as the value that needs to be set).